# Is 'coin' a non-count noun?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

I noticed that in banks' publications, they speak of [*notes and coin*](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22notes%20and%20coin%22) (rather than *coins*).

So, is *coin* a non-count noun, like *fruit* and *fish*?

We'd say, "Do you have any *fruit/fish* in your fridge?" (rather than *fruits/fishes*).

Should we also say, "Do you have any coin in your drawer?"

Comment: Yes, "coin" is often used in that way in banks, shops etc where they are dealing with large quantities. However we still talk about "the coins in my pocket or purse". One wouldn't use the non-count version other than with someone who kept both notes and coin.

Comment: _Coin_ is not a non-count noun in everyday speech. Banks use it in the special sense of 'money in coins rather than notes'.

Comment: It can be non-count, although usually it's count. I'd say *any coins in your drawer.*

Comment: Both *fruit* and *fish* can be used in a countable way. *I ate two fruits* and *I ate two fishes* are both grammatical, even if not common.